# Return the second-smallest value from a list

Tags: haskell

```
min2 :: Ord a => [a] -> a
min2 x =  if g  == minimum x then minimum x else g
  where
    g = minimum(filter (> minimum x) x)
```

this only works for list where there is only one minimum value;
so min2 [2110, 4820, 2110, 4120] != 2110, it counts 2110 as a single element not 2

The code is all I have right now, how can I account for the repeated element

Comment: Why not just sort and take the second element? BTW, `if g  == minimum x then minimum x else g` is logically the same as simply `g`, no matter what `g` is, and that's not connected to the fact you're taking the minimum.

Comment: Preferably I use filter or filter, and I was hoping minimum wouldnt count the element as one

Comment: Try [Data.List.delete](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:delete). Or write your own – it's not difficult.

Comment: @RobinZigmond “why not just sort” – well _O_ (_n_ · log _n_) would be quite a valid reason why not. So, to this comment it's important to add that Haskell is able to avoid that through laziness.

Comment: @leftaroundabout  If `sort` is implemented as a merge sort, then thanks to laziness it is actually run as a kind of heap sort (I remember this being discussed a long time ago). In such case, it would have the nice property that demanding the first k elements costs only O(n · log k), IIRC. When k=2, that is O(n) which is optimal. This fact is not at all obvious, though, and a nice example about why reasoning about complexity in a precise way can be kind-of hard in Haskell.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I did initially plan to comment about laziness, but didn't because the filtering algorithm already must look at every element so it didn't seem performance would the main concern.

Comment: @chi probably *O(n + k log n)*. and that is what leftaroundabout was saying. :) I wonder whether a sort implementation is possible where `(!! k) . sort` would be equivalent to an *O(n)* (even if just on average) *kth-smallest*...

Answer (score 1):

First sort the list and then select the second element of the resulting intermediate list (if any):

```
import Data.List (sort)

min2 :: Ord a => [a] -> a
min2 xs = case sort xs of
  []           -> error "min2: empty list"
  [x]          -> error "min2: singleton list"
  (x : y : xs) -> y
```

```
> min2 [2110, 4820, 2110, 4120]
2110
```

Or, if you want a more obvious linear-time solution, you could simply traverse the input list and maintain an accumulating parameter that stores the two smallest values encountered so far:

```
data Acc a = Empty | Singleton a | Min2 a a

min2' :: Ord a => [a] -> a
min2' = fromAcc . foldl go Empty
  where
    go Empty x         = Singleton x
    go (Singleton y) x
      | x < y          = Min2 x y
      | otherwise      = Min2 y x
    go (Min2 y z) x
      | x < y          = Min2 x y
      | x < z          = Min2 y x
      | otherwise      = Min2 y z

    fromAcc Empty         = error "min2': empty list"
    fromAcc (Singleton x) = error "min2': singleton list"
    fromAcc (Min2 x y)    = y
```

```
> min2' [2110, 4820, 2110, 4120]
2110
```

Comment: your first function, `min2`, is also linear, since `sort` is implemented as mergesort. the implicit tree of comparisons has *O(n)* nodes, is built in *O(n)* time in the bottom-up manner, and each element of the sorted result is produced in *O(log n)* time.

Comment: Thanks, @WillNess, you're right of course. It's just that via `sort` linearity is less obvious; I'll update the answer accordingly. (Also, one could consider it an implementation detail of `sort` as the documentation for `Data.List.sort` leaves the sorting method unspecified.)

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the list of items, and then pick the second item. For example:

```
import Data.List(sort)

min2 :: Ord a => [a] -> Maybe a
min2 xs
    | (_:x:_) <- sort xs = Just x
    | otherwise = Nothing
```

The `sort` function is implemented as a [lazy mergesort where it first  [src]](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/Data.OldList.html#sortBy) with some extra optimizations. That means if you for example obtain the *k*-th element, it will run in *O(*k×log *n+n)* time, so for the second item, it will run in *O(n)*.